# Mouse Move Boots System After Powering Off

Tags: mouse

It may be coincidence, but I've just connected a new optical **USB** mouse and now, after I POWER OFF the system, a slight move of the mouse will TURN ON and boot the PC.  I can't find a solution in the Power or Mouse section of **Settings**, so what can I do?  Thanks.

(I had to turn Mouse Speed all the way down to make it move at a sane speed.)

**Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect its a hardware setting (ie. bios/uefi setting) & won't be affected by any setting in the Ubuntu/OS.

Comment: If I didn't do it explicitly, I wonder what could've changed the setting.

Comment: on some machines; a failing battery (small cmos battery) can cause memory loss & settings being lost..  if battery has been replaced (or on test shows its good), I'd wonder if the new usb mouse draws more power than the 'off/standby' setting allows for (many 'off' or really standby machines still have hardware functioning...)

Comment: It shouldn't be the battery, as I've just recently purchased this new motherboard.  If it's the mouse, then I may regret buying a USB model instead of the Y splitter for my old PS/2 devices.

Comment: I've used BIOS to disable "waking" by mouse, and I've confirmed that the keyboard will "wake" the PC.  I say "wake" because it's really not in sleep/standby mode;  I POWER OFF the system and when the mouse/keyboard turns it on, it goes thru the whole boot process, and any apps that were running at power-off are now closed.